# Sqlalchemy dynamically build or_ conjunction and_

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to generate a dynamically conjunction with or_ and and_ but not the SQL query generates or.

The number of operators or_ and and_ varies for each query.

query:

```
q = se.query(Publicacion.update_time).join(Categoria).order_by(Publicacion.update_time.desc())
q = q.filter(and_(Publicacion.id_group_id == '103738479786979'))
q = q.filter(and_(Publicacion.id_categoria_id == 1),)
q = q.filter(and_(Categoria.estatus == True),)
q = q.filter(or_(Publicacion.message.ilike('%Obsequios%')),)
q = q.filter(or_(Publicacion.message.ilike('%jose%')))
q = q.filter(or_(Publicacion.message.ilike('%compu%')))
```

out sql:

```
SELECT showgroups_publicacion.update_time AS showgroups_publicacion_update_time 
FROM showgroups_publicacion JOIN showgroups_categoria ON showgroups_categoria.id = showgroups_publicacion.id_categoria_id 
WHERE showgroups_publicacion.id_group_id = %(id_group_id_1)s AND showgroups_publicacion.id_categoria_id = %(id_categoria_id_1)s AND showgroups_categoria.estatus = true AND showgroups_publicacion.message ILIKE %(message_1)s AND showgroups_publicacion.message ILIKE %(message_2)s AND showgroups_publicacion.message ILIKE %(message_3)s ORDER BY showgroups_publicacion.update_time DESC
```

**At the end I solved this way, if there is a more elegant, share it:**

```
Y = and_ (column1 == 1)
Y = and_ (column2 == 'SQL',Y)

O = or_ (column1 == 2)
O = or_ (column2 == 'Python',O)

session.query(Model).filter(or_(O,Y))
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the use of `or_`, `and_` and `filter`. [Look at the tutorial for a correct example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#conjunctions).

You should specify more than a clause inside `and_` (and `or_`), like you do in every programming language. Instead of writing this:

```
q = q.filter(and_(Publicacion.id_group_id == '103738479786979'))
q = q.filter(and_(Publicacion.id_categoria_id == 1),)
q = q.filter(and_(Categoria.estatus == True),)
```

You should have written this:

```
q = q.filter(and_(
    Publicacion.id_group_id == '103738479786979',
    Publicacion.id_categoria_id == 1,
    Categoria.estatus == True,
))
```

The same holds for `or_`.

Now I don't know what you had in mind, so I can't tell you how the two `and_` and `or_` clauses should be combined in your case. *Probably* you wanted to do this:

```
q = q.filter(
    Publicacion.id_group_id == '103738479786979',
    Publicacion.id_categoria_id == 1,
    Categoria.estatus == True,
    or_(
        Publicacion.message.ilike('%Obsequios%'),
        Publicacion.message.ilike('%jose%'),
        Publicacion.message.ilike('%compu%'),
    ),
)
```

---

What you were doing by using multiple `filter` with single-condition clauses was essentially this:

- An `and_`/`or_` with a single condition is superfluous, so that `filter(and_(something))` is equivalent to `filter(or_(something))`, which is equivalent to `filter(something)`.
- You were issuing multiple `filter`, that can be combined into only one. Your code is 100% equivalent to:

  ```
  q = q.filter(
      Publicacion.id_group_id == '103738479786979',
      Publicacion.id_categoria_id == 1,
      Categoria.estatus == True,
      Publicacion.message.ilike('%Obsequios%'),
      Publicacion.message.ilike('%jose%'),
      Publicacion.message.ilike('%compu%'),
  )
  ```

  The behavior of `filter()` is to `AND` every condition. In fact, your query contained only `AND`.

  By the way, note that `filter(and_(a, b, c, ...))` is equivalent to `filter(a, b, c, ...)`.

Comment: +1, thanks Andrea certainly had not understood how to use operators, although the solution that you raise is for a case with fixed operators have added the dynamic solution I found.